# Databricks Spark Reference Applications: State maintenance using static variables in Spark Streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

[1.1.3.2 Cumulative Calculations](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-reference-applications/content/logs_analyzer/chapter1/total.html) section mentions usage of static variables for maintaining:

- runningCount
- runningSum
- runningMin
- runningMax

My Understanding: In Distributed Mode, the DStream: `contentSizeDStream` (an infinite series of RDDs) would be partitioned and distributed amongst multiple Workers for processing, and *each Worker will have its own copy of `static` variables* (runningCount...runningMax).

Q: **How would `static` variables help in maintaining an [SSOT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth) state?**

Code snippet:

```
JavaDStream<Long> contentSizeDStream =
accessLogDStream.map(ApacheAccessLog::getContentSize).cache();
contentSizeDStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
if (rdd.count() > 0) {
runningSum.getAndAdd(rdd.reduce(SUM_REDUCER));
runningCount.getAndAdd(rdd.count());
runningMin.set(Math.min(runningMin.get(), rdd.min(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
runningMax.set(Math.max(runningMax.get(), rdd.max(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
System.out.print("Content Size Avg: " + runningSum.get() / runningCount.get());
System.out.print(", Min: " + runningMin.get());
System.out.println(", Max: " + runningMax.get());
}
return null;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the `DStream` represents a distributed stream data, the operations reveal a multi-level abstraction: Operations that apply to elements, such as `map`, `filter`, and their classical friends all operate distributed in the cluster. 
In the code above, `accessLogDStream.map(ApacheAccessLog::getContentSize)` is an example of that. `contentSize` will apply distributed over the elements of the `accessLogDStream`.

Then, we have operations that apply to `RDD`s, such as `transform` and `foreachRDD`. They operate on the underlying RDD abstraction. The code in the closures of these operations gets attached to the SparkStreaming scheduler and execute on the driver, *not distributed*. Yet, as they provide access to an `RDD`, we can still apply distributed operations to the RDD and get the results to the single driver context.

Going back to the example code, `runningCount` is a variable local to the context of the driver. When we do `runningCount.getAndAdd(rdd.count());` we are effectively applying a distributed `count` operation over the `rdd`, collecting the totalized count over all partitions and executors to the driver and then adding that number to the value of `runningCount` in the local context.

That way, the streaming program we can keep a centralized summary of the data distributed in the cluster, which can be further consumed by other applications that are interested in the results of the streaming job.